# Spring data solr with start and rows

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I know we can do paging in the Spring data solr using pageable interface.But how can get data using start and rows rather than a page?

```
Page<Student> findByName(String name, Pageable page)
```

The above function returns me the a page with the specified count. here if i set page=2 and count=10.it returns 21 to 30 items.
But i require 2 to 10 items here.

So here,i don't want paging.i require start and rows same like solr.
How can i do this ?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SolrTemplate` and `SimpleQuery` to influence *start* and *rows*.

```java
Query query = new SimpleQuery(where("name").is(name))
  .setOffset(2)
  .setRows(8);

Page<Student> page = template.queryForPage(query, Student.class);
```

Comment: This is fine.But i am looking for a way to do it in Repository.Can i do it?

Comment: Not directly - you'll have to do it via a [custom repo implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).